# Change a subfolder in git repository to be a new repository while keeping history

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a project named *Project_A* which contains a folder ***Pro_A*** which is used by *Project_B* as a submodule. I would like to make ***Pro_A*** a standalone project and have both *Project_A* and *Project_B* to use it as a submodule. Is there a way to do this while preserving history for ***Pro_A***

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+detach+subdirectory

Answer (score 1):

One way to maintain the history is to clone the original repo, then delete the folders you don't want and commit it. Similarly, you can delete the folders from the original repo that you want in the new repo.